# Most efficient way to find specific objects in a list

Tags: java, android

I have a custom object.

```
public class StatusItem {

    private final String key;
    private final String value;

    public StatusItem(String key, String value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Then I have a long list of those objects.

```
List<StatusItem> statusItems;
```

Currently, I'm just iterating over them and acting on the matches I find.

```
for (StatusItem statusItem : mStatusItems()) {
        switch (statusItem.getKey()) {
            case "apple":
                doStuff();
                break;
            case "oranges":
                doSomethingElse();
                break;
}
```

Is this the optimal way of doing things? I'm interested to know whether there are more efficient ways of accomplishing the same thing or at least a way that results in less code.

I know I could use the Stream API or equivalent methods to obtain specific items in a list, but since I'm looking up multiple items I'm assuming it would be inefficient since it would effectively look through the entire list for every item instead of just iterating through it once like I currently do.

Comment: With object contain key-value info you should use HashMap and use contains method to perform action

Comment: Good idea. I'm getting the list from a network API but I could easily just convert it to as Map. It would mean iterating through the list once though.

Comment: hmm, as I know you can parse from Json to Map directly without iterating list and init map

Comment: even better, thanks